# One input component but different states for each occurrence

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have created a component element. I am using it in a `form`.

I put the state in the class for the input component and when i do `console log` and they all seem to share the same `state`? is this normal. will need to post the values into `laravel` api and store to `mysql` next. is the following correct or do i need to create an input component for each field i require. Eg. one for name, one for surname one for telephone one for email etc:

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './Input.module.scss';

export class Input extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      inputValue: ''
    }

    this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  onInputChange(e) {
    this.setState({ inputValue: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
console.log(this.state.inputValue)

    return (
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <label htmlFor={this.props.id} className={styles.label} > {this.props.label} </label>
        <input 
          id={this.props.id}
          className={styles.input}
          type="text"
          value={this.state.inputValue}
          onChange={this.onInputChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

reusing same component here:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.contactForm} >
        <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
          <div className={styles.contactBlock} >
            <div className={styles.header} onClick={this.onStepOneClick} >
              <BoxHeader title="Step 1: Your Details" />
            </div>
            <div className={styles[this.state.stepOne]}>
              <div>
                <Input type="text" label="First Name" id="name" /> 
                <Input type="text" label="Surname" id="surname" />
              </div>
              <div>
                <Input type="email" label="Email Address" id="email" />
              </div>
              <div className={styles.button} onClick={this.onStepOneClick}>
                <Button innerHTML="Next >" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className={styles.contactBlock} >
            <div className={styles.header} onClick={this.onStepTwoClick} >
              <BoxHeader title="Step 2: More Comments" />
            </div>
            <div className={styles[this.state.stepTwo]}>
              <div>
              <Input type="tel" label="Telephone Number" id="tel" />
              <Select label="Gender" id="gender" >
                <option> Male </option>
                <option> Female </option>
                <option> Other </option>
              </Select>
              </div>
              <div>
                <Date label="Date of Birth" id="dob"/>
              </div>
              <div className={styles.button}  onClick={this.onStepTwoClick}>
                <Button innerHTML="Next >" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className={styles.contactBlock} >
            <div className={styles.header} onClick={this.onStepThreeClick} >
              <BoxHeader title="Step 3: Final Comments" />
            </div>
            <div className={styles[this.state.stepThree]}>
                <div className={styles.textArea}>
                  <Textarea label="Comments" id="comment" /> 
                </div>
                <div className={styles.submit}>
                  <Submit innerHTML="Next >" />
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
```

Comment: `value={this.state.inputValue}` this would capture the correct value.  You don't need to do `console.log`.

Comment: console log is just there for me to see.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for each field you would need to create a new input. This can be within same or new component whichever you prefer.

Comment: But we make components so we can reuse them. Is there not a way to make this reusable?

Comment: Can you share the code where you're using the Input Component. @Yappyhappy